# Why didn't Starfleet ever check on Khan?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, the-wrath-of-khan

> Starfleet... never bothered to check on our progress

-Khan, *Star Trek II, the Wrath of Khan*

I understand that the odds of the neighboring planet exploding and causing the other planet to shift into its orbit in such a way as to utterly destroy the climate on said neighbor is very very low. But it seems rather irresponsible to me not to at least pay them a visit.

At the end of *Space Seed*, it seems that this was a legitimate Federation punitive measure (given Kirk et al busted out the fancy uniforms) which to me made it seem like the Federation was somewhat obligated to ensure they didn't die down there.

What gives? Why didn't Starfleet, at the very least, do a drive by? (In canon, please)

Comment: Kirk deleted the details from their database and stranded Khan

Comment: @Valorum source?

Comment: @Valorum why would he delete the database? Do you have a source?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/90016/20774 - To stop Khan from escaping or being rescued

Comment: Is that a canon source?

Comment: @GridAlien - The novelisations are generally considered to be canonical. Or not. Take your pick, really.

Comment: Starfleet seems to have the tendency to just sweep things under the rug. They beamed Lore into space without checking on him, in the direct vincinity of a dangerous being that he has communicated with in the past. And they have the tendency to not follow up on _anything_: They once found a guy who evolved into being immortal and able to heal anyone and let him go without even exchanging phone numbers.